# Is it possible for a user app to capture a screenshot(anytime) in android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to capture a screenshot of whatever view the user has, in android using a user app - without rooting/adb. So basically i want to create a screenshot app. Hopefully my doubt is clear enough. Not enough info is there whether android allows the user app to do this or not.

Comment: What have you done to research this?

Comment: O google, official android developer chat, stackoverflow. What i found was that some 2011 reports of gingerbread supporting it, then on stackoverflow in 2011 only i believe some person with 30k reputation said it cannot be done. But now it s 2012.

Comment: Android does not allow to make screenshots outside of your own app because that can be abused as a trojan like spy thing. You can check if it is possible if you find apps in the market that can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to capture a screenshot of whatever view the user has, in android using a user app - without rooting/adb.

In your own app, you can have the activity render its UI to a bitmap-backed `Canvas`.

For other apps, this is not possible at the OS/SDK level, for obvious privacy and security reasons. There are some devices with security flaws that enable this capability.